# Excel Table If statement on table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi so I have a table that has Peoples names and a "helper column" that lists numbers: 1-45 in "sheet2"
In my Sheet1 i have the numbers 1-45 seperated by about 12 rows each time in column A but the rows inbetween have text, Im looking to say: "if helper column is = to the number in sheet1 then paste persons name of which is nexto the number"

Sheet 1:

"1"

| Person | Info | Info 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| no data | info here | info here |

"2"

| Person | Info | info 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| No data | info here | info here |

Sheet 2:

| People | Helper |
| --- | --- |
| Mr human | 1 |
| Ms Human | 2 |
| miss human | 3 |
| Dr Human | 4 |

Currently my code stands as :

```
=IF(List!B46=Master!A1147,List!A46)
```

how do I change this to look at the table rows and that?

thanks for the help!

Comment: You have to write formula for each list. What is your actual goal?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are describing is a good use case for index(match(
Your sheet names and columns are so obfuscated I can't give an exact formula,
Try something like:

```
=index(Sheet2!B:B,match(A46,Sheet2!B:B,0))
```